# Creating multiple thread groups in jmeter Testplan

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I want to create 80 thread groups on Jmeter test plan, 1 thread group for 1 user. Can somebody help me  with an easy way to achieve this? I'm using jmeter for the first time and the only way i know is to copy a thread group and rename after pasting

Comment: Why you need it? What is your use case? You can change 1 thread group to loop 80 times or execute 80 users

Answer (score -1):

Duplicating code is not the best idea, consider using [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) 
 or Include Controller instead, this way you will be able to call a [Test Fragment](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) as many times as required.